# Orthogonally diagonalizing a matrix given a linear mapping, without calculating the original matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let f:R^3 ---> R^3 be the linear mapping which reflects over the plane 3x-2y+z=0. The goal of this question is to orthogonally diagonalize the matrix [f] without calculating [f].

(a) Determine an orthanormal basis for the plane

(b) Determine all eigenvalues of [f]. For each eigenvalue, describe it's eigenspace, and find an orthanormal basis for it.

(c) Find an orthogonal matrix Q and a diagonal matrix D such that Q^T[f]Q=D

(d) explain why [f] must be symmetric

(e) determine det[f]

I can get part (a), but I have no idea how to go about getting the eigenvalues...

Comment: Hello torigabrielle. What you want to do is complete the orthonormal basis $(v_1,v_2)$ you found in part (a) to an orthonormal basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ of all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now what are $f(v_1)$, $f(v_2)$, $f(v_3)$, expressed in the basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$? If you can answer that question, then you will be able to write the matrix of $f$ in the basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$. That will answer (b) and (c).

Comment: so is v3 just a vector that's independent of v1 and v2 then?

Comment: Not only that - you need the three together to form an orthonormal basis, since you want the matrix $Q$ to be orthogonal.

Comment: How would I go about finding V3 then? Thanks by the way, I appreciate your help.

Comment: $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal and have length $1$. In his answer, Sami suggests a way of getting a vector $v_3$ that has length $1$ and is orthogonal to both of them.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Take two linearly independent vectors of the given plane and construct from it an orthonormal basis of the plane $(v_1,v_2)$ using the Gram-Schmidt process. Let $v_3=v_1\wedge v_2$. Notice that $f(v_1)=v_1$ and $f(v_2)=v_2$ and $f(v_3)=-v_3$ and the eigenvalues are $1,1,-1$. The matrix $Q=(v_1\; v_2\;v_3)$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-1)$. Notice that $Q$ is orthogonal i.e. $Q^T=Q^{-1}$
so $[f]$ is symmetric. The determinant of $[f]$ is the product of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can find an orthonormal basis without gram-schmidt. here is how:
first find three orthogonal vectors two of which are in the plane. pick $v_1 = [3, -2, 1]^T$. now a vector orthogonal to this is $v_2 = [0,1,2]^T$ finding a vector orthogonal to these two vectors is the null space of a matrix made up these two rows. from the selection of the rows this matrix is already in row echelon form with $z$ being the free variable.  so $v_3 = [5, 6,-3]^T$. the reflection $f$ has this effect on these vectors: $f(v_1) = -v_1, f(v_2) = v_2$ and $f(v_3) = v_3.$ with $q = [v_1/|v_1|, v_2/|v_2|, v_3/|v_3|],$ we have $T[f]q = q\  diag(-1, 1, 1)$ and $q^Tq = qq^T = I_3.$